# readbytes of a file and running it

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, byte

I have 2 .net files ! once with c#.net and another one with vb.net :)

Now I want read the bytes of it and running it :)

```
Dim mybyte As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("E:\Projects\Expired.exe") 
System.Reflection.Assembly.load(mybyte)
```

> Could not load file or assembly '8192 bytes loaded from mybyte

Comment: I think that exe file prevent from  Reflection.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to run it that specific way?

Comment: for security of my information , I want encode it and then decode it in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the file, do your stuffs (decrypt?), then write the content to a new file and run it.
Something like that (you can embed your file in the project resources if you want):

```
// Read file content from project resources
byte[] fileContent = MyProject.Properties.Resources.MyFile;

// <Do your stuffs with file content here>

// Write new file content to a temp file
string tempFile = "yourfile.exe";
File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile , fileContent );

// Run the app
Process proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(tempFile));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check if:

- the *.exe you want to load is .NET/managed code
- all dependencies that are required by your *.exe are present
- that your application is built against the same (or newer) version of
  .NET that the *.exe you want to load

You may also read [the best practices of assembly loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks ... now I have a new problem ; for example if I want showing a messagebox it isn't show !